# Instances on Specific Points

Tags: geometry, geometry-nodes, instances

Currently in Geometry Nodes, the `Instance on Points` mode maps instances to points uniformly throughout an object (by vertices or samples). Is it possible to specify which points/vertices to use for `Instance on Points`? For example, if a curve has 5 vertices, could I assign an instance to the 1st, 3rd, and 5th vertices respectively?
[image: Instances on Points]
Thank you!

Comment: Just connect index node to modulo 2 and put it in selection.

Comment: Hi @Chris, thank you for the reply. Could you please explain `modulo 2`? I see the `Modulo` enum in the Math node but I'm not sure how to use this to control which vertices receive an instance.

Comment: Perhaps there's useful information in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214160/how-to-use-vertex-group-to-instance-an-object-in-geometry-node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i mean like this: index increases from 0 to number of points. Modulo 2 makes out of that a list of 0,1,0,1,0 ...

[image]

result with selection:

[image]

result without selection:

[image]

[image]

to get the 3 and 7th you do this for selection:

[image]

Note: this is an index compare. So 3 and 7 are in reality 4 and 8 !

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, scene file, and screenshots. It's very helpful. I was hoping to be more specific about which vertices. I used 1, 3, and 5 as an example, but I'd also like to just be able to target more arbitrary indices such as 3 and 7 (so something not requiring math). Do you have any advice for that?

Comment: you can compare the index with whatever values you like. So you could compare with 3 and 7 and maximum that result and put it in the selection. If my answer helped you, please check the checkmark left to my answer. thanks.